# How does server or client know if connection broken?

Tags: go, streaming, grpc

I am not able to figure out internal working of `grpc streaming`. I have a scenario where I have server side streaming and if I remove the client from the network (by pulling out network cable, lets say), I am not getting any error or client or server side.

Can someone please help here?

If I kill server, client gets to know. If I kill client, server gets to know. But disconnection is not getting identified.

I am interested to know why this is not working and how it works in case server or client is killed. Is there some `heartbeat` message sent to check connectivity or how is it done? I mean, if I send data every 30 sec, how does it work?

Answer (score 3):

The internet would not work if intermediate network paths temporarily disappeared.
Idle network connections should be able to tolerate temporal network path disappearances.

The reason you are seeing server/client connections abort when either side disconnects, is because of a proactive teardown of the connection from the application layer (network layer 7) on downwards.
Disconnecting a physical cable, only severs the [physical network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_architecture) and its effects do not necessarily cascade upwards, especially with an idle connection.

If your application specs insist on a certain level of "liveliness" - say an event even a heartbeat every 30 seconds - you can ensure the server always sends even a `NOP` (heartbeat) to the gRPC stream. In this case the server will experience the network outage (at worse) within 30 seconds.

Similarly, if you are concerned the client may be waiting on a connection that is no longer reachable, a timer looped go-routine could be employed on the client-side to cancel the connection context if a record (even a heartbeat) has not bee received in the last 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

gRPC supports keepalives between your client and server:
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/keepalive